# How do I fix the argument received from getopt?

Tags: bash, bash-script, getopts

I have the following commands in my script:

```
set -- `getopt -q agvc:l:t:i: "$@"` 
... 

while [ -n "$1" ] 
do 
-i) TIME_GAP_BOOT=$2 
shift ;; 

... 
sleep $TIME_GAP_BOOT
```

When invoking the script with `-i 2`, I get the error

```
sleep: invalid time interval `\'2\''
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly format the argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bash builtin `getopts` is a lot easier to use. If you're using `bash`, you should use it instead of `getopt`.

GNU `getopt` is designed to work with arguments which have whitespace and other metacharacters in them. In order to do that, it produces a result string with bash-style quotes (or csh-style quotes, depending on the `-s` option.) You need to arrange to have the quotes interpreted, which requires the use of `eval`. (Did I mention that the bash builtin `getopts` is better?).

The following example is from the getopt distribution; I had nothing to do with it. (It should be present on your machine somewhere; with ubuntu and debian, it shows up as `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash`. I'm only quoting a few lines:

```
# Note that we use `"$@"' to let each command-line parameter expand to a 
# separate word. The quotes around `$@' are essential!
# We need TEMP as the `eval set --' would nuke the return value of getopt.
TEMP=`getopt -o ab:c:: --long a-long,b-long:,c-long:: \
     -n 'example.bash' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

# Note the quotes around `$TEMP': they are essential!
eval set -- "$TEMP"
```

In addition to the quotes which the example's comment points at, it's important to look at the `eval`, which is generally frowned upon.

By contrast, the bash builtin `getopts` requires no `eval`, and is quite straightforward; it basically emulates the standard C library call:

```
while getopts agvc:l:t:i: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
   i) TIME_GAP_BOOT=$OPTARG;;
   # ...
  esac
done
```

Comment: +1 even though i strongly disagree that the `getopts` built-in is better than `getopt` from the util-linux package.  `/usr/bin/getopt` supports --long options, built-in `getopts` doesn't.  the real advantage of `getopts` over `getopt` is that getopts is part of the POSIX sh standard, and is available (nearly) everywhere, while `getopt` is not guaranteed to be installed.  personally, i always use /usr/bin/getopt in my own scripts - for me --long option support worth the minor effort of installing it wherever i need it.